# Html Annotator,Html Converter in Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

Can anyone briefly explain about the Html annotator, Html converter and TEIViewWriter with some examples.I want to create annotations in the initial view.

Awaiting for the Answer.

Main Script:

```
 PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
 SCRIPT uima.ruta.example.Html;
 Document{-> EXEC(Html)};
 WORDLIST JOURNALNAMELIST='JournalName.txt';
 WORDLIST CITYPUBLIST='CITYPUB.txt';
 DECLARE JOURNALNAME;
 DECLARE CITYPUB;
 Document{ -> MARKFAST(JOURNALNAME, JOURNALNAMELIST)};
 Document{ -> MARKFAST(CITYPUB, CITYPUBLIST)};
 DECLARE Reference;
 "<a name=para(.+?)>(.+?)</a>"-> 2=Reference;
 DECLARE FirstToken, LastToken;

 BLOCK(InRef) Reference{}
 {
 ANY{POSITION(Reference,1) -> MARK(FirstToken)};
 Document{-> MARKLAST(LastToken)};
 }
 DECLARE FIRSTWORD;
 FirstToken PERIOD CW {->MARK(FIRSTWORD)};
```

Html Script:

```
 PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
 ENGINE utils.HtmlAnnotator;
 ENGINE utils.HtmlConverter;
 ENGINE utils.HtmlViewWriter;
 TYPESYSTEM utils.HtmlTypeSystem;
 TYPESYSTEM utils.SourceDocumentInformation;
 Document{-> EXEC(HtmlAnnotator)};
 Document { -> CONFIGURE(HtmlConverter, "inputView" = "_InitialView","outputView" = "plain"),
 EXEC(HtmlConverter)};
 Document{ -> CONFIGURE(HtmlViewWriter, "inputView" = "plain","outputView" = "_InitialView", "output" = "E:/ruta-2.4.0-source-release/ruta-2.4.0/example-projects/TextRulerExample/output"),
 EXEC(HtmlViewWriter)};
```

Sample Html Input file:(manually converted into html by changing extension)

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)">
 <style>
 <!--
/* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
 {margin-top:0in;
 margin-right:0in;
 margin-bottom:10.0pt;
 margin-left:0in;
 line-height:115%;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
span.DAZZLEFN
 {mso-style-name:DAZZLEFN;}
span.DAZZLELN
 {mso-style-name:DAZZLELN;
 color:#92D050;}
.MsoChpDefault
 {font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
.MsoPapDefault
 {margin-bottom:10.0pt;
 line-height:115%;}
@page WordSection1
 {size:8.5in 11.0in;
 margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
 {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

<body lang=EN-US>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p class=MsoNormal><a name=para0>REFERENCES</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para1>1.����������� Lawrence RA. A        review of the
 medical benefits and contraindications to breastfeeding in the United    States
 [Internet] . Arlington (VA): National Center for Education in Maternal and
 Child Health; 1997 Oct [cited 2000 Apr 24]. p. 40. Available from:
 www.ncemch.org/pubs/PDFs/Welcometojungle.pdf.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para2>2.����������� Shishido A.  Retraction notice:
 Effect of platinum compounds on murine lymphocyte mitogenesis [Retraction of
 Alsabti EA, Ghalib ON, Salem MH. In: Jpn J Med Biol 1979 Apr; 32(2):53-65].      Jpn
 J Med Sci Biol 1980 Aug;33(4):235-237.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para3>3.����������� Leist TP,  Zinkernagel RM.
 Effects of treatment with IL-2 receptor specific monoclonal antibody in mice
 [letter] [Retraction of Leist TP, Kohler M, Eppler M, Zinkernagel RM. In: J
 Immunol 1989 Jul 15; 143(2): 628-32]. J Immunol 1990 Apr 1;144(7):2847.</a>  </p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para4>4.����������� Alsabti EA, Ghalib     ON, Salem MH.
 Effect of platinum compounds on murine lymphocyte mitogenesis [Retracted by
 Shishido A. In: Jpn J Med Sci Biol 1980 Aug; 33(4):235-7]. Jpn J Med Sci  Biol
 1979 Apr;32(2):53-65.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para5>5.����������� Tidy JA, Parry GC, Ward P,
 Coleman DV, Peto J, Malcolm AD, Farrell PJ. High rate of papillomavirus type 16
 infection in cytologically normal cervices [letter] [Retracted by Tidy J,
 Farrell PJ. In: Lancet 1989 Dec 23-30:2(8678-8679):1535]. Lancet 1989 Feb   25;1(8635):434.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para6>6.����������� Magni F, Rossoni G,  Berti F.
 BN-52021 protects guinea-pig from heard anaphylaxis. Pharm Res Commun 1988
 Dec;20 Suppl 5:75-78.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para7>7.����������� Garvia EE, DeHaven ED. An
 experimental analysis of response acquisition and elimination with positive
 reinforcers. Behav Neuropsychiatry 1975 a April-1976 May;7(1-12):71-78.</a>  </p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para8>8.����������� Mueller FO,   Schindler RD. Annual
 survey of football injury research 1931-1985. [place unknown]: American
 Football Coaches Assn; 1986. 24 p.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para9>9.����������� Stern, Michael P.   National
 Institute of Arthritis, Diabetes, and Digestive and Kidney Diseases.   Diabetes
 in America: diabetes data compiled 1984.. [Bethesda (MD)]: The Institute; 1985
 Aug. Diabetes in Hispanic Americans. Chapter 9. (NIH publication; no. 86- 1468).</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para10>10.��������� Vivian, Valerie L,      editor. Child
 abuse and neglect: a medical community response. 1st AMA National   Conference on
 Child Abuse and Neglect; 1984 March 30-June 31; Chicago. Chicago: American
 Medical Association; 1985. 256 p.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para11>11.��������� Popper, Hans, et al.,   editors.
 Structural carbohydrates in the liver: proceedings of the 34th Falk   Symposium;
 1982 oct 12-19; Basil, Switzerland.Boston: MTB Press; 1983. 701 p.</a></p>

 <p class=MsoNormal><a name=para12></a>&nbsp;</p>

 </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you example script does not contain the mentioned TEIViewWriter. The problem is the same, however.

Unfortunately, the exemplary script has an error:

The line

```
Document{ -> CONFIGURE(ViewWriter, "inputView" = "plain",...
```

should read

```
Document{ -> CONFIGURE(HtmlViewWriter, "inputView" = "plain",
```

... then the NPE is gone. There could be another exception if the input text is not parseable by the HtmlParser resulting is a missing Sofa in the XMI file. Wrapping the text in  could help here.

The files HtmlConverter.ruta and TEIConverter.ruta [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/example-projects/Misc/script/uima/ruta/example/) are indeed good examples for these components
The HtmlAnnotator creates annotations for HTML and XML tags/elements. The HtmlConverter removes all HTML/XML tags, stores the resulting text in a new view and recalculates the offsets of the annotations. The TEIViewWriter is just a ViewWriter with a specific type system, which copies a specific view to a new CAS and stores it. Together, these components are able to convert a TEI/Html/XML text to plain text with annotations for the xml markup.

The [documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae) contains more information, e.g., about the configuration parameters

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: May 23, 2016 4:03:57 PM org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.HtmlConverter mapAnnotations(454) WARNING: illegal annotation offset mapping May 23, 2016 4:03:57 PM org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.HtmlConverter mapAnnotations(454) WARNING: illegal annotation offset mapping. I'm receiving this message in the console.Whether it will affect my output.

Comment: I'm receiving two xmi files in the output.Reference.html.xmi and output.xmi.

Comment: Do I need to call the main ruta script from the html Script? Orelse it is enough to add the TypeSystem of the main script file.Because the type(eg:DZC_CITYPUB) is not annotated in the Reference.html.xmi.

Comment: The warning is logged if the converter tries to produce an annotation with illegal offsets, e.g., length 0 because all text was removed. In my use cases this never caused a problem.

Comment: Can you laborate  on the setup with the two files? The main script imports and calls the html script as a script (not an AE) and executes it with CALL?

Comment: When I import and call the html script from my main script.I found that number of occurence are reduced and some tags are missing.

Comment: Which tags are missing? I did not find any problems yet when reproducing it.

Comment: CITYPUB and FIRSTWORD  is missing.FIRSTWORD is not tagged due to the space(���������) after the FirstToken.

Comment: Ah ok, I assume you want to create the annotations like CITYPUB in the plain view and not in the initial view?

Comment: First thing is to remove the line `Document{-> RETAINTYPE(SPACE,BREAK)};` in the Html Script. EXEC is not sensible to the filtering settings anyway. The annotations are added to the _Initialview. With EXEC you can apply analysis engine to a different view, but not with CALL. If you want to apply the rules on the plain view, you need some sofa mapping.

Comment: The space(���������) is not considered as a space.It is tagged as a Special.Why?.

Comment: What I want to do ,If I want to create the annotations in the plain text view.

Comment: Is it a NBSP or which kind of space is it? NBSP should be SPACE and NBSP is defined as: `u00A0|\u202F|\uFEFF|\u2007|\u180E|&nbsp;|&NBSP;`

Comment: That issue was solved.Now What I want to do ,If I want to create the annotations in the plain text view.

Comment: You told that I need some sofa mapping to apply the rules on the plain view,Can you explain it briefly.

Comment: Sofa mappings are described in the UIMA documentation, e.g., [here](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-current/tutorials_and_users_guides.html#ugr.tug.mvs.sofa_name_mapping). If there are problems, you should rather create a new question.

Comment: Ok I will ask in new question.

Comment: The Script is working perfectly in ruta project.But If I use it in a maven project I'm receiving some errors.

Comment: Which errors? Does this refer to the new question. If yes, you could add the errors there.