# How to ignore MARKUPs from ruta output or from JCas?

Tags: maven, uima, ruta

I'm executing a ruta script dynamically from a Java Maven project. The script annotates an HTML file and the output is processed further. Now that the coveredText contains HTML tags in between as below;

(a+b) < SUP >2< /SUP> ==> is MARKed as formula

But I want it as

(a+b)2 ==> where the superscription is captured as another annotation and handled later.

How to arrive at the expected solution ?

Comment: In UIMA, the document text is static. If you want to change the text, you need to create a new view/CAS. In ruta, there are three components that can create a cas with modified document text: HtmlConverter, RutaModifier,  RutaCutter. If you want to process it further, you need an aggregate AE with sofa mapping.

Comment: How to do it ? Plz help me with some coding or links. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In UIMA, the document text is static. If you want to change the text, you need to create a new view/CAS. In ruta, there are three components that can create a cas with modified document text: HtmlConverter, RutaModifier, RutaCutter. If you want to process it further in the same pipeline, you need an aggregate AE with sofa mapping (or a sofa aware analysis engine).

There is some documentation about these [analysis engines](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae) and their [usage](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#section.tools.ruta.howto.xml). There is also an [example project](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/example-projects/Misc) of these rules and and a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154527/html-annotator-html-converter-in-uima-ruta) which discusses some possible problems. Information about Sofa mapping can be found in the [UIMA documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-current/index.html)

*(DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta)*